# SQL Access Query like expression not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to test a query using 'like' but i'm not getting any results back.  I tried using UPPER() but when I executed the query, access said that UPPER was undefined?

```
SELECT ITEM.Category, ITEM.Description
FROM ITEM
WHERE ITEM.Category LIKE '%Plate%';
```

Comment: What's your exact requirement?

Comment: I remember the wildcard in ms access is '*' instead of '%', try this....

Comment: LIKE question is already answered. As for the `UPPER` - use `UCASE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT ITEM.Category, ITEM.Description
    FROM ITEM
    WHERE ITEM.Category LIKE '*Plate*';
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly..I wasn't aware that access had some different syntax than oracle / SQL Server.